# Calling a method of existing object using IL Emit

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core, cil

I am attempting to write an attribute based interceptor (something similar to `DynamicProxy`). The idea being, based on certain custom attributes, a method inside that attribute would be called, i.e.

- Call a method  inside attribute class before actual method is called.
- Call the actual method.

I am able to override existing method using `MethodBuilder` and `TypeBuilder`. However, I can't figure out how to call the method inside the Attribute.

My code :

```cs
static void CreateMethods<T>(TypeBuilder tb)
        {
            foreach (var methodToOverride in typeof(T).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
            {
                var attribute = (ProxyMethod)methodToOverride.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(ProxyMethod));
                if (attribute == null)
                    continue;

                MethodBuilder methodBuilder = tb.DefineMethod(
                    methodToOverride.Name,
                    MethodAttributes.Public
                    | MethodAttributes.HideBySig
                    | MethodAttributes.NewSlot
                    | MethodAttributes.Virtual
                    | MethodAttributes.Final,
                    CallingConventions.HasThis,
                    methodToOverride.ReturnType,
                    Type.EmptyTypes
                );

                ILGenerator il = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "The I.M implementation of C"); //step1
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) })); //step1

                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, methodToOverride);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

                tb.DefineMethodOverride(methodBuilder, methodToOverride);
            }
        }
```

What I think I should do is load `attribute` onto stack, then call `attribute.attributeMethod()` by emitting a call to the `MethodInfo`. However, everywhere I look, I can find examples of creating a new instance of the objected using `OpCodes.NewObj`. I don't want to use this, because attributes may have parameters.

I can't think of any of calling the method inside attribute class (which would replace step1 comment).

EDIT: Based on comments, I'm trying to move the `GetCustomAttribute` part of the code in IL. This is what I have right now

```cs
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, methodToOverride);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, typeof(ProxyMethod));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Attribute).GetMethod("GetCustomAttribute", new [] { typeof(MemberInfo), typeof(Type) }));
```

It throws an error for me. Any tips?

Comment: You need to emit the code for loading the attribute as well, as you cannot pass the attribute instance to the generated code. Remember, when that code runs yours doesn't, so only simple primitives and metadata independent of your code can be passed directly, not locally created objects. (As attributes are instantiated from metadata it would theoretically be possible to somehow emit the data necessary for instantiating it instead of getting the attribute, but I see no benefit to that.)

Comment: Can you provide an example? If I move getting the attribute part of the code to IL, I would still need to put `typeof(ProxyMethod)` on top of stack. I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: That one's easier: if you investigate the IL the compiler emits for such code (with LINQPad, for example) you'll see you need an `ldtoken` opcode. (In fact, by investigating the compiled code for this method you can see how to move parts of it inside the generated code. Also, where possible rely on calling non-generated code, inside well-known static methods for example, as the less code you need to generate the easier.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert can you take a look at edit please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic code generation is always kind of annoying. Let's cook up some helper methods first to get rid of all the `.GetMethod` stuff:

```
static class Method {
    public static MethodInfo Of<TResult>(Expression<Func<TResult>> f) => ((MethodCallExpression) f.Body).Method;
    public static MethodInfo Of<T>(Expression<Action<T>> f) => ((MethodCallExpression) f.Body).Method;
    public static MethodInfo Of(Expression<Action> f) => ((MethodCallExpression) f.Body).Method;
}
```

Now let's say we have `ProxyMethodAttribute` and its method `MyMethod` -- here's how we'd retrieve that and call it:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, methodToOverride);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, Method.Of(() => MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(default(RuntimeMethodHandle))));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, typeof(ProxyMethodAttribute));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, Method.Of(() => Type.GetTypeFromHandle(default(RuntimeTypeHandle))));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, Method.Of(() => Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(default(MemberInfo), default(Type), default(bool))));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, Method.Of((ProxyMethodAttribute a) => a.MyMethod()));
```

Note how we need to call `GetXXXFromHandle` to produce actual instances from the metadata tokens generated, and how we need a more involved call to `Attribute.GetCustomAttribute` (`MethodInfo.GetCustomAttribute` doesn't actually exist, this is implemented as an extension method.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jeroen. Can you explain what the IL code is doing?

Comment: Basically nothing more than calling `GetCustomAttribute(methodToOverride, typeof(ProxyMethodAttribute), true)` to get the `ProxyMethodAttribute` on `methodToOverride`, and then it invokes `MyMethod` on the attribute instance so returned. The only tricky bits are the `Get...FromHandle` calls we need to get method and type handles from the [metadata tokens](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldtoken). We get these and not instances for the same reason we can't pass the attribute instance -- the generating code can't pass object instances to the generated code.

Comment: I mean, I can't figure out what the call emits to here. For example, I get you are loading the `MethodInfo` in 1st line, but I got no idea what you are doing in the second. Similarly, for all the "Calls", I don't understand what you are doing. On another note, can you explain what `GetXXXFromHandle` actually does? AFAIK, they convert `IntPtr`s and `Handle`s to proper methods. I don't understand how it is used in current context.

Comment: The first line *doesn't* load the `MethodInfo`, it loads a metadata token based on the `MethodInfo`. You can't pass these tokens to methods, for that you actually need `MethodInfo` and `Type` instances (which `GetCustomAttribute` needs), and that's what the `GetXXX` methods produce. It goes "`MethodInfo` (generating code) -> `ldtoken <mdtoken>` -> `GetMethodFromHandle` -> `MethodInfo` (generated code)". We cannot directly emit code to load the `MethodInfo` we have in the calling code, since there's no (direct) IL representation of that object (unlike, say, the integer `1`).

Comment: Note how it might look like `Call` allows us to directly pass a `MethodInfo`, but this is only because `Call` actually takes a metadata token, not a `MethodInfo`. We have to jump through these hoops because we need to call `GetCustomAttribute`, which needs an actual method and type and not a metadata token.

Comment: That is a pretty good explanation, thanks! However, I can't run your code as is. It throws `An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidProgramException' occurred in DynamicProxy.dll: 'Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.'`.Am I missing something?

Comment: Turns out I forgot to add `OpCodes.Ret` at the end. That works like a charm man. Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: Just a follow up, could you explain how the last line works? If I'm not wrong, in the 2nd last line, the attribute itself is on the stack. How did the last line get `a`?

Comment: There is no `a` -- I'm just passing an `Action` that captures the `MethodInfo` in an `Expression`, the parameter's a dummy (and the call in that `Action` never happens). It's the same as `il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(ProxyMethodAttribute).GetMethod("MyMethod"))`, but without the string hardcoding or possibility of ambiguity about what method I want. The attribute instance is indeed on the stack, and `MyMethod` is invoked on it by virtue of being an instance method.

Comment: Aah, that explains it. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Hey man, that's for your help, but could you also take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59658409/loading-a-parameterinfo-using-il-emit