# Loading a ParameterInfo using IL Emit

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

I am currently using [Calling a method of existing object using IL Emit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640074/calling-a-method-of-existing-object-using-il-emit/58643509?noredirect=1#comment103609359_58643509) as a guide, and I can already do whatever is asked in question. Now, I have an attribute added to a parameter and I want to load that particular parameter's attribute so that I can call a method inside that attribute.

I know it can be done by loading the `MethodInfo` and then getting the `ParameterInfo` and then getting attribute of that `ParameterInfo` in IL; I am simply trying to avoid writing that much IL.

Is there a way to load a parameter's attribute in IL just like it is mentioned in the linked post?

Edit:
I have a method with a signature like

```cs
Method([Attr] int Parameter)
```

and I want to load a method which is part of the `Attr`. I was just hoping I could load `ParameterInfo` (obtained using `MethodInfo.GetParameters()`) directly onto the stack. Turns out, `LdToken` doesn't really allow putting `ParameterInfo`. Only other way I can think of doing this is to load `MethodInfo` (`LdToken` supports that) and then use `GetParameters()` in IL to get an array of Parameters and then loop through them in IL one by one to get each one's `Attribute` (using `.GetCustomAttribute(Type)`) and then call the method on that attribute. Note that I don't have to get a field of an attribute, I need to call a method on that attribute.

Comment: to be clear: when you say "attribute", you really mean "property" or "field", right?

Comment: Nope, I really mean attribute. My signature is something like `Method([Attr] int Parameter1)` and I need to load `[Attr]` and pass `Parameter1` to it. I was kind of hoping that I could load the `ParameterInfo` directly using IL but looks like I can't. The only other alternative I could think of is to load `MethodInfo` and get the `ParameterInfo` through `GetParameters()`

Comment: I think a concrete example is needed, frankly; an attribute isn't actually a thing that exists at runtime; it is pure metadata - the runtime can *synthesize* instances of attributes, but that is exactly that: a synthesis

Comment: Marc, I can't really put an example as my code is really messy at this point. It will cause more harm than good. I tried to explain best of capability but I think both of us can concur that emitting proper IL code is the way to go.

Comment: "I can't really put an example as my code is really messy at this point" - then put a minimal example that shows the point you're trying to achieve; creating a minimal example is a pretty important skill; I'll try to give an example, sec...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I actually went ahead and loaded `ParameterInfo` using IL only. Marc's solution was good, but it quickly became infeasible after the number of parameter based attributes increased. We plan to use attributes to contain some state specific information, we would have to use a ton of reflection from outside the type to find and assign correct attribute to the field. Overall, it would have become quite hectic to deal with it.

To load `ParameterInfo` using IL

```cs
IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, Method); // Method is MethodInfo as we can't use GetParameters with MethodBuilder
IL.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(MethodBase).GetMethod(nameof(MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle), new[] { typeof(RuntimeMethodHandle) }));
IL.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(MethodInfo).GetMethod(nameof(MethodInfo.GetParameters)));
var ILparameters = IL.DeclareLocal(typeof(ParameterInfo[]));
IL.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, ILparameters);
```

that loads `ParameterInfo` onto stack and then stores it into a `LocalBuilder` called `ILparameters`. Note that it is an array. Items of this array can then be accessed like

```cs
IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, ILparameters);
IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, Number); // Replace with Ldc_I4_x if number < 8
IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelem_Ref);
```

I prefer to create two helper functions for the two code pieces. It works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

K, third time lucky based on *another* interpretation of the question; here, we're assuming that we want to invoke methods on an attribute instance. We need to consider that attributes only *kinda sorta* exist at runtime - we can create synthetic instances of the attribute as represented by the metadata, but this isn't particularly cheap or fast, so we should ideally only do this once (the metadata isn't going to change, after all). This means we might want to store the instance as a field somewhere. This could be an instance field, or a static field - in many cases, a static field is fine. Consider:

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

public class SomethingAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SomethingAttribute(string name)
        => Name = name;
    public string Name { get; }

    public void SomeMethod(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"SomeMethod: {Name}, {i}");
    }
}
public static class P
{
    public static void Foo([Something("Abc")] int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Foo: {x}");
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        // get the attribute
        var method = typeof(P).GetMethod(nameof(Foo));
        var p = method.GetParameters()[0];
        var attr = (SomethingAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(p, typeof(SomethingAttribute));

        // define an assembly, module and type to play with
        AssemblyBuilder asm = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("Evil"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        var module = asm.DefineDynamicModule("Evil");
        var type = module.DefineType("SomeType", TypeAttributes.Public);

        // define a field where we'll store our synthesized attribute instance; avoid initonly, unless you're
        // going to write code in the .cctor to initialize it; leaving it writable allows us to assign it via
        // reflection
        var attrField = type.DefineField("s_attr", typeof(SomethingAttribute), FieldAttributes.Static | FieldAttributes.Private);

        // declare the method we're working on
        var bar = type.DefineMethod("Bar", MethodAttributes.Static | MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(void), new[] { typeof(int) });
        var il = bar.GetILGenerator();

        // use the static field instance as our target to invoke the attribute method
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld, attrField); // the attribute instance
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // the integer
        il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(SomethingAttribute).GetMethod(nameof(SomethingAttribute.SomeMethod)), null);
        // and also call foo
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // the integer
        il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, typeof(P).GetMethod(nameof(P.Foo)), null);

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        // complete the type
        var actualType = type.CreateType();
        // assign the synthetic attribute instance on the concrete type
        actualType.GetField(attrField.Name, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(null, attr);

        // get a delegate to the method
        var func = (Action<int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<int>), actualType.GetMethod(bar.Name));
        // and test it
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            func(i);
    }
}
```

Output from the final loop (`for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) func(i);`):

```
SomeMethod: Abc, 0
Foo: 0
SomeMethod: Abc, 1
Foo: 1
SomeMethod: Abc, 2
Foo: 2
SomeMethod: Abc, 3
Foo: 3
SomeMethod: Abc, 4
Foo: 4
```

As a side note; in many ways it is *easier* to do this with expression-trees, since expression-trees have `Expression.Constant` which *can be* the attribute instance, and which is treated like a field internally. But you mentioned `TypeBuilder`, so I went this way :)

Comment: Very interesting. Keeping attributes as private fields really is a nice idea. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

> I know it can be done by loading the `MethodInfo` and then getting the `ParameterInfo` and then getting attribute of that `ParameterInfo` in IL; I am simply trying to avoid writing that much IL.

Yeah, that's pretty much it, in IL; IL is powerful, but is *not* particularly terse or simple. Just like in the linked post, you'd end up loading the parameter (ldarg or ldarga, maybe some .s), then depending on whether the member is a field or a property, using either ldfld or callvirt on the property getter. About 3 lines, so not *huge*; perhaps something like:

```cs
static void EmitLoadPropertyOrField(ILGenerator il, Type type, string name)
{
    // assumes that the target *reference*  has already been loaded; only
    // implements reference-type semantics currently
    var member = type.GetMember(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Single();

    switch (member)
    {
        case FieldInfo field:
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
            break;
        case PropertyInfo prop:
            il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, prop.GetGetMethod(), null);
            break;
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

---

If you're trying to save complexity (or are sick of `InvalidProgramException`), another viable approach is to use expression trees; then you have many more convenience features, but in particular things like:

```cs
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo), "x");
var name = Expression.PropertyOrField(p, "Name");
// ...
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<YourDelegateType>(body, p);
var del = lambda.Compile();
```

Note that expression trees cannot be used in all scenarios; for example, they can't really be used with `TypeBuilder`; conversely, though, they *can* do things that IL-emit can't - for example, in AOT scenarios where IL-emit is prohibited, they can work as a runtime reflection evaluated tree, so it still *works* (but: slower). They add some additional processing (building and then parsing the tree), but: they are *simpler* than IL-emit, especially for debugging.

Comment: I really was trying to avoid doing all the IL emits, but looks like that's the way to go for me. I can't exactly use expression trees since they don't play well with other `TypeBuilder` things I got. Also, I need to load an attribute inside a `ParameterInfo`, not a field or property. My signature is something like `Method([Attr] int Parameter)`.

Comment: @Crimson7 (attribute) - fair enough; I did try to clarify that on the question, but; yeah; getting attribute metadata is similarly fun, but: attributes don't change at runtime, so you shouldn't have to do anything with IL emit in that case - just reflection on the attribute. Perhaps a real example of the value you're after would be a good edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

With the clarification that by attribute you really did mean a .NET attribute (not a field or property), this becomes simpler in many ways; consider:

```cs
class SomethingAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SomethingAttribute(string name)
        => Name = name;
    public string Name { get; }
}
static class P
{
    public static void Foo([Something("Abc")] int x) {}

    static void Main()
    {
        var method = typeof(P).GetMethod(nameof(Foo));
        var p = method.GetParameters()[0];
        var attr = (SomethingAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
            p, typeof(SomethingAttribute));
        string name = attr?.Name;
        // you can now "ldstr {name}" etc
    }
}
```

The important point here is that the attribute isn't going to change at runtime - it is pure metadata; so, we can load it once with reflection when we are processing the model, then just emit the processed data, i.e. the line

```cs
// you can now "ldstr {name}" etc
```

Comment: That's pretty much like my setup, except I need to call a method on the attribute. Catch is this has to be done using IL since I am generating a lot of code on runtime. Expression trees are not an option either since most of my codebase is already uses `TypeBuilder` and converting everything to expression trees would set me back by at least a month.

Comment: Clarification, the class `P` and `Foo` already exist and they are non IL. What I have to do, is to run `P` through a function which generates a derived type of `P` and goes through all the members. This function would then load `Something` from `Foo` and that attribute would have a method called `FooBar` and we have to call that method and pass it `x`. This behavior is similar to `PostSharp` but for "corporate reasons" we can't use that or any of the other AOP libraries.